# Detecting isolated eigenvalues from local spectral measures

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sp.spectral-theory, ergodic-theory, hilbert-spaces

**Please note:** *This question has been edited after it became clear from Christian Remling's answer that the original formulation was far from what I really meant to ask.*

Let $T\ne 0$ be a self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $H$, with spectrum $\sigma(T)$. For any $x∈H$, denote by $μ_x$ the spectral measure of $T$ at $x$, that is the unique Borel measure on $\sigma(T)$ such that

$$ ⟨x,f(T)x⟩ = \int_{\sigma(T)} f(λ) d \mu_{x}(λ) \quad \forall f \in \mathcal{C}(\sigma(T),\mathbb{C}). $$

Then, one can prove that
$$ \overline{\bigcup_{x\in X} Supp(\mu_x)}=\sigma(T)$$
for any orthonormal basis $X$ of $H$.

Suppose that there exists a closed subspace $H_0$ of $H$ and a positive integer $k$ such that $T|_{T^i H_0}$ is injective for all $i=0,\dots,k-1$, and $$ H=H_0 \overset{\perp}{\oplus} TH_0 \overset{\perp}{\oplus} \dots \overset{\perp}{\oplus} T^{k-1} H_0,\qquad T^{k}H_0=H_0.$$

If $k=1$, then $T$ is invertible, hence $0\in \sigma(T)$ if and only if the inverse $T^{-1}$ is unbounded. Therefore, either $0\not\in \sigma(T)$ or $\lambda=0$ is an accumulation point of $\sigma(T)$.

Suppose now that $k\ge 2$, and suppose that there is an orthonormal basis $X_0$ of $H_0$ such that $\mu_x(\{0\})>0$ for all $x\in X_0$. Then, one has $0\in \sigma(T)$. Under some additional assumptions I can actually show that $\lambda=0$ must be an isolated eigenvalue. However, I was actually wondering whether that might always be the case.

**Addendum:** This is how I would like reason. Let
$$ X:=X_0\cup TX_0 \cup \dots \cup T^{k-1}X_0. $$

Let $\mathfrak{M}$ be the set of discrete positive measures $\nu$ on $X$ with the following property:  $$\forall A\subseteq X,\; \nu(A)=0\implies \nu(TA)=0.$$

Then, for all non-zero $\nu\in\mathfrak{M}$, one has $\nu(X_0)>0$. Hence $$ \int_{X} \mu_{x}(\{0\})d\nu(x) \ge \int_{X_0} \mu_{x}(\{0\})d\nu(x)>0.$$

It seems to me that this could be enough to conclude that $\lambda=0$ must be an isolated eigenvalue. However, I can only show this with extra assumptions.

**Addendum:** It occurred to me that the case $k\ge 3$ is not that interesting because one gets
$$ 0=⟨x,T^2 x⟩ = \int_{\sigma(T)} \lambda^2 d \mu_{x}(λ) \implies \mu_{x}=\delta_0.$$
The case $k=2$ (which is actually also the one that motivated this question) is thus the only really interesting case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated answer:**
For $k=2$ the conditions are contradictory.

We have the decomposition $H=H_0\oplus H_1$. You now impose the following conditions: (1) $TH_0=H_1$; (2) $T$ injective on $H_0$ and $H_1$; (3) $T^2 H_0=H_0$; (4) $Tu=0$ for some $u\notin H_1$.

Since $N(T^2)=N(T)$ for the self-adjoint operator $T$, we can rephrase the last condition as: (4') $T^2u=0$ for some $u\notin H_1$.

Let's write
$$
T= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & B \\ B^* & C \end{pmatrix} ,
$$
and here the components refer to this decomposition of $H$; the zero in the $(1,1)$ is a consequence of (1) above.

In terms of $B,C$, your conditions become: (1') $B^*$ surjective (onto $H_1$); (2') $B^*$ injective (on $H_0$) and also if $By=Cy=0$, then $y=0$; (3') $BC=0$, $BB^*$ surjective; (4'') $BB^*x=$ for some $x\in H_0$, $x\not= 0$.

Since $B^*$ is injective, (4'') shows that $N(B)\not= 0$, but since $N(B)=R(B^*)^{\perp}$, this contradicts (1').

---

**Comment:** The part below answers the original version of the question.

It does follow, but in a rather trivial, disappointing way. Let $S$ be the operator $T^k$, restricted to its reducing subspace $H_0$. Since $N(T^k)=N(T)$ for a self-adjoint operator, we have $N(S)= N(T)\cap H_0$. By assumption, if $x\in H_0$, $x\not= 0$, then $x\notin N(T)^{\perp}$, so $x\notin N(S)^{\perp}$. Thus $S=0$ and hence $T=0$ as well on $H_0$. But then $H=H_0$, and your operator was the zero operator all along.

Comment: Mmm, that's something weird going on. This question is motivated by many explicit examples that come up from my research in which clearly $T\ne 0$ and $H\ne H_0$.

Comment: I have adapted the formulation of the question a little to eliminate the only potential problem I could see. As an example, you can take the l^2 adjacency operator of a (c,d)-biregular tree with $c\ne d$.

Comment: For the case $k=1$, I don't have any interesting example, so it might be that it would follow that $T=0$. In any case, I am actually mostly interested in the case $k\ge 2$ (in the example in the previous comment one has $k=2$).

Comment: The case $k=1$ is indeed not very interesting. I have worked it out and added to the question. The positiveness of local spectral measures at zero would indeed imply that $T=0$ in the case $k=1$.

Comment: @MaurizioMoreschi: Now it's a different situation, of course. There's a huge difference between "for all $x\in H_0$" (the question you asked originally) and "there is an ONB of $H_0$ for which..." (the edited version).

Comment: If I may make a general comment, please try to avoid this kind of moving target question, where you change it to a different question after the first version has been answered.

Comment: You are perfectly right, sorry. I didn't realize at all that there were something wrong with the formulation until reading your answer. The current formulation is what I really meant.

Comment: @MaurizioMoreschi: Yes, no problem, thanks for clarifying. I was just trying to make a general comment (especially since this is a widespread and somewhat unfortunate phenomenon on MO).

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer. I am not going to modify the question again, but if with k=2 it's contradictory, then it is clear that I have not manage to get to the right formulation of what I want to ask yet (I have namely concrete examples of the situation I have in mind, when k=2).